# Extracting (get) second string if exists after splitting, otherwise first

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a bunch of strings based on a phrase and get the second element. However, in the cases where the string cannot be split, I want to retain the first element. Here is an example showing my current approach, where I by default always extract the second element:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : ["this is a (test), it is", "yet another"]})
df["a"].str.split("\(test\)", 1).str[1]
```

As you can see, this (incorrectly) gives me

```
0    , it is
1        NaN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

whereas my desired output should be

```
0     , it is
1    yet another
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with original column `a`:

```
df['b'] = df["a"].str.split("\(test\)", 1).str[1].fillna(df["a"])
#alternative
#df['b'] = df["a"].str.split("\(test\)", 1).str[1].combine_first(df["a"])
print (df)
                         a            b
0  this is a (test), it is      , it is
1              yet another  yet another
```

Comment: Thanks, what an elegant solution. Do I need to add an `r` as a prefix to my expression in `split`, i.e. does it have to be `split(r"\(test\)", 1)`? Or does it suffice without the `r` as it is now?